# SQL JOIN query fails

Tags: sql, join

I am going through an online SQL tutorial doing the exercises and now I am in the JOIN section to be found here: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

We are given 3 tables and we are supposed to join them and then run queries to answer questions.

All the details can be found at the wepage to which the hyperlink above directs but for your convenience the image of the table is shown below:

[image]

In answering the first question I am getting an exception.

The question is:

> show the matchid and player name for all goals scored by Germany.

My code is:

```
SELECT goal.matchid, goal.player
FULL JOIN goal, eteam
ON goal.teamid = eteam.id
WHERE eteam.teamname = 'GER'
```

I am getting the following feedback:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN goal, eteam ON goal.teamid = eteam.id WHERE eteam.teamname
>   = 'GER'' at line 2

Can you explain the cause of the exception and how to correct the code?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: After you fix your syntax error: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After an OUTER JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". Looks like after you fix your syntax error you'll have that. Although you actually want an INNER JOIN for this query.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. (Why write what you did?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need  a FROM clause and a JOIN  clause  (and not a comma separated  list of table after the FULL JOIN.. your syntax is wrong)

```
  SELECT goal.matchid, goal.player
  FROM goal
  FULL JOIN  eteam  ON goal.teamid = eteam.id
  WHERE eteam.teamname = 'GER'
```

Anyway, seems you need  an inner join.

```
  SELECT goal.matchid, goal.player
  FROM goal
  INNER JOIN  eteam  ON goal.teamid = eteam.id
  WHERE eteam.teamname = 'GER'
```

Comment: Both the inner and full join return correct answers.  For some reason the syntax goal.teamid returns an error, does not recognize the column.  I have to enter the column with its name only (e.g. teamid).

Answer (score 0):

The actual syntax of `full join`

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

so write you query this way

```
SELECT goal.matchid, goal.player 
from goal
FULL JOIN eteam
ON goal.teamid = eteam.id
WHERE eteam.teamname = 'GER'
```